# Metro MediaCapture MFT Effect Explaination

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, webcam, effect, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to apply an effect on a mediacapture stream for a WPF app I'm porting over to Metro. In the WPF app I used Pixel shaders to modify a bitmap whose source was set to the stream of a webcam, but since effects have been dropped for Metro I'm looking for an alternative solution.

The best, and most Metro standards compliant, way of doing this that I've found is building my own MFTs and adding them to my `MediaCapture` element via the `addEffectAsync()` method. I've downloaded the MFTGrayscale and MediaExtension examples which show how to apply these effects to a `MediaCapture` element, but I'm having an issue understanding the actual C++ MFT code. Can someone point me to or give a decent walkthrough/explanation of how I'd go about building my own MFT effect from the ground up? I don't know too much C/C++, just enough to understand some of the example code. I'm really having trouble with the conceptual and architectural aspects of MFT, and hence am very confused by the source code.

Your help is very much appreciated.

EDIT:

Another option I'd consider is using SharpDX. However I'm having issues getting a stream of the `MediaCapture` object to display on a xaml image element. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should absolutely have a look at the following git repo: https://github.com/mmaitre314/VideoEffect

It shows how to apply image effects from the Lumia Imaging SDK, Win2D, and DirectX HLSL pixel shaders to videos in Universal Store Apps for Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1.

Effects can be applied via MediaTranscoder, MediaComposition, MediaCapture, or MediaElement. And the binaries are available via NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting answer on the MSDN forums. It's not an ideal answer, but it's what I'd been fearing all along.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/f3a6934e-df7a-44da-bfd8-7b95d494ff43/#90690f89-e57d-4043-9881-60fcc587f736

Answer (score 0):

This is totally doable... I've just rewritten one of the MF transforms from the samples to use the Nokia Imaging SDK and apply filters in real-time to webcam video.  You can see how I did it at the link below (plus download some source code).  It's not exactly what you need to do, but in the wiki page I explain what you need to change from the boilerplate sample that MS provided.

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Template_universal_app_for_video_recording_with_MediaCapture_using_Imaging_SDK_Filters